# When you're dealing with C and other languages that have pointers, does initializing a pointer automatically set it to null?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say you have defined a (global or local) pointer variable such as this:

```
    void *this_is_a_pointer;
```

without giving it the value " = NULL; "

Would this automatically give you a NULL ptr (a pointer that points to NULL)?

***** Also, what does it mean for a null pointer to point to NULL? Is that saying that it could point to literally *anywhere*? (basically, what really is the "address location of *NULL*"?)

Comment: a) What languages other than C (and C++, which for pointers follows almost all the same rules as C) do you mean? b) Use formatting. c) What is `(void *)this_is_a_pointer;` supposed to mean? That looks like a cast, not a declaration.

Answer (score 7):

> (global or local)

This is actually what makes the difference.

In general, if you didn't initialize a variable, it's not initialized and reading from it is undefined behavior. But if the variable has *static storage duration*, then it's automatically initialized to zero (null for pointers).

```
// foo.cpp

void* this_is_null;

void whatever(void)
{
    static int* and_so_is_this;
}

void not_whatever(void)
{
    float* but_this_local_is_uninitialized;
}
```

Comment: But aren't implementations allowed to have others values for NULL, especially in debug mode? I think I've seen Visual Studio show NULL pointer values as 0xCCCCCCCC in the watch window.

Comment: @Praetorian: Good debugging compilers will secretly initialize "uninitialized" variables to a magic value to aid in debugging, but null pointers have a specific value (though it's implementation-defined.)

Comment: @GMan: I was just confused whether global variables are also categorized as "static storage duration" or they are strictly referred to as global variables?

Comment: @DarkTemplar: Pedantically, there's no such thing as a "global variable", it's a term we programmers use to refer to something that's accessible from any scope. Typically a global is something in *file scope*. But yes, global variables, in the orthodox sense, have static storage duration.

Comment: @DarkTemplar: Though I want to add, and make it clear, that you should **always initialize your variables**, regardless of what rules might happen to initialize it to what you need, just for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely do **not** count on this. Compilers in Debug mode (with the correct switch settings) will typically zero variables on the stack for you to track down bugs, but it is better to explicitly initialize all of your variables not just pointers.

**EDIT:** In response to your edit, the value of NULL is defined as zero. So, it would point to address 0, which in most modern operating systems would result in a segmentation fault, or memory access violation. But, on some embedded operating systems with little memory management it would let you change the contents of address 0! This one has bit me a few times ;)

Comment: So even for a global variable (or variable pointer), you'd want to go ahead and explicitly initialize it where it's been declared at the top of the file, even before you've reached your constructor?

Comment: @DarkTemplar: Yup. It's a mental spee-dbump to have to stop and figure out if your variable qualifies for automatic zero-initialization. While this may be important in some esoteric circumstances, in most cases you just want to initialize it and forget the whole thing.

Comment: Yes, the standard does say that your static and global variables will be initialized to zero. But, as GMan has suggested, it is good practice to always initialize your variables instead of relying on how a compiler may or may not implement the language standard because then you are at the mercy of the compiler writers.

Comment: Compilers in debug mode may also set uninitialized stack variables (more precisely, objects with automatic storage duration) to some non-zero garbage.

Answer (score 1):

[C Tutorial – More on Pointers](http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-more-on-pointers)

> Initialise a pointer
>
> Before you can use a pointer in for instance a printf statement, you
>   have to initialize the pointer. The following example will not
>   initialize the pointer:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

void main()

{

    int *ptr_p;

    printf("%d\n",*ptr_p);

}
```

> Note: We used void when we declared the function main(). So no return
>   0; is needed. (Some compilers will give a warning when void is used on
>   main(). GNU compiler will give the warning: return type of ‘main’ is
>   not ‘int’).
>
> In this example we print the value that ptr_p points to. However, we
>   did not initialize the pointer. In this case the pointer contains a
>   random address or 0.
>
> The result of this program is a segmentation fault, some other
>   run-time error or the random address is printed. The meaning of a
>   segmentation fault is that you have used a pointer that points to an
>   invalid address.

[10.4 Null Pointers](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10d.html)

> The most straightforward way to ``get'' a null pointer in your program
>   is by using the predefined constant NULL, which is defined for you by
>   several standard header files, including , , and
>   . To initialize a pointer to a null pointer, you might use
>   code like
>
> #include
>
> int *ip = NULL; 
>   < and to test it for a null pointer before inspecting
>   the value pointed to you might use code like
>
> ```
>           if(ip != NULL)
>   printf("%d\n", *ip);
> ```
>
> It is also possible to refer to the null
>   pointer by using a constant 0, and you will see some code that sets
>   null pointers by simply doing
>
> int *ip = 0;
>
> (In fact, NULL is a preprocessor macro which typically
>   has the value, or replacement text, 0.) Furthermore, since the
>   definition of ``true'' in C is a value that is not equal to 0, you
>   will see code that tests for non-null pointers with abbreviated code
>   like
>
> if(ip)      printf("%d\n", *ip);
>
> This has the same meaning as our
>   previous example; if(ip) is equivalent to if(ip != 0) and to if(ip !=
>   NULL). All of these uses are legal, and although I recommend that you
>   use the constant NULL for clarity, you will come across the other
>   forms, so you should be able to recognize them.

Comment: Woah! What kind of C tutorial uses `void main()`?

Comment: @ChrisLutz Well, it id CodingUnit ^_^.

Comment: @KeithThompson I can remove it if it is that bad Mr.Thompson, I really don't want to disturb Ritchie in his grave.

Comment: The rest of it is ok; on the other hand, other answers cover it pretty well.  And I've submitted a comment (awaiting moderation) on the tutorial site.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer with *static storage duration* will be automatically initialized to NULL.  A pointer with auto duration will not be initialized, and will contain a random value that may or may not correspond to a valid memory address:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *p0; // File scope, initialized to NULL

int main(void)
{
  static int *p1; // Declared "static", initialized to NULL
  int *p2;        // Auto, not initialized

  printf("p0 = %p, p1 = %p, p2 = %p\n", (void *) p0, (void *) p1, (void *) p2);
  return 0;
}
```

There is the null pointer *constant*, which is 0 (the macro NULL expands to a 0-valued pointer expression).  There is the null pointer *value*, which may or may not be 0-valued; it's the value used by the underlying system to indicate a well-defined "nowhere".  When a null pointer *constant* appears in your code, it will be replaced with the null pointer *value*.

A null pointer value is guaranteed to compare unequal to any valid pointer value.